# Hashtable contains() doesn't read char type

Tags: java, char, hashtable

For some reason, my hashtable's `contains()` method isn't working. I'm trying to create a hashtable that records how many times each letter is found in a word.

`character : # of occurrences`

I would appreciate any insight into what I am doing incorrectly.

```
Hashtable<Character, Integer> table = new Hashtable<Character, Integer>();
char[] array = word.toCharArray();

//inserting letters into table
for (char letter : array) {

    //letter is already in table
    if (table.contains(letter)) {
        int x = table.get(letter);
        x++;
        //overwriting with updated value
        table.put(letter, x);
    }
    //if letter is not already in table
    else {
        table.put(letter, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the contains method looks for the values, not the keys, you have to use the containsKey() method which receives chars in your case
it should look like this

Update: how about this refactor?

```
        String word ="hello";
    Hashtable<Character, Integer> table = new Hashtable<Character, Integer>();

    //inserting letters into table
    int x;
    for (char letter : word.toCharArray()) {

        //letter is already in table
        if (table.containsKey(letter)) {
            x = table.get(letter)+1;
        }
        //if letter is not already in table
        else {
            x=1;
        }
        table.put(letter, x);
    }
    System.out.println( table);
```

Comment: ... I'm a fool. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code and this is my output    {l=2, h=1, e=1, o=1}